# split string based on certain delimiter using batch script

Tags: batch-file

Can anyone please help me to get the following output from given input values using batch script?

Input Values:

```
{"name":"John:Doe","age":"30","occupation":"Software Engineer"}
```

Output Values:

```
name="John:Doe" age="30" occupation="Software Engineer"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "input={"name":"John:Doe","age":"30","occupation":"Software Engineer"}"

for %%a in (%input:~1,-1%) do for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%b in ("%%a") do (
   echo %%~b=%%c
)
```

Output:

```
name="John:Doe"
age="30"
occupation="Software Engineer"
```

Do you need the output in the same line?

---

Another way:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "input={"name":"John:Doe","age":"30","occupation":"Software Engineer"}"

set "input=%input:~2,-1%"
set "input=%input:":"=="%"
echo %input:","=" %
```

Output:

```
name="John:Doe" age="30" occupation="Software Engineer"
```

Comment: Hi Aacini,
Thanks for your response. Solution 1 is serving my purpose. However If I have ashtrix "*" in the value, this solution is not working. Could you please help?
Example: {"Pwd":"Wdr[*iut-$"}

Comment: Solution 1 don't works if input have asterisk or question-mark. Use solution 2, it works Ok. Just tested...